# How do I get a List of elements of a given sub-class from the original List Class?

Tags: java, list, oop

Sorry if the title seems awkward. Didn't really know how to phrase the question.
Suppose I have a method in which I want to get all instances of given Class, is this correct?

```
class Test{
    private List<A> list;
    //... all properly iniatialized on constructor

    //...
    public List<A> getSubListOfGivenClass(Class c){
        //if i can't assign an instance of a Class c to Class A - error, not subclass
        if(!A.class.isAssignableFrom(c))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        List<A> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(A aItem : list)
           if(c.isInstance(aItem))
              newList.add(aItem);
        return newList; 
    }
}
```

Or is this problem solved way easier using Generics? (I don't know much about them that's why I am asking this question, if I can do this without bothering with Generics).
And sorry again if I made any mistake with synthax or something, just wrote this code here to serve as an example.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pretty sure your `getSubListOfGivenClass` method itself is sound.  The need to have it to begin with is what seems questionable to me.  But without more concrete detail, it's hard to be certain how to fix it (if fixing it should be fixed).

Comment: @Ironcache to avoid aving a separate method for each different sub-class that I may have, instead of having getSubListOfBInstances(), getSubListOfCInstances(), etc...

Comment: +1 to @Ironcache's comment.  How are you planning on using this?  I would consider a factory constructor that creates each subclass and keeps a references to each instance in some kind of container for subsequent retrieval

Comment: @amirafghani That's why I am asking, this is pretty tricky to use, I wanted a better option to do the same job, but without the trouble of Class objects.

Comment: @DavidFrickert I agree you probably don't want to have a method for each subclass.  But my concern is on a deeper level; why do you want to know about the subclasses of A?  You rarely *need* to rely on `instanceof` or `isInstance()` calls.  Perhaps you can give us more details about "A"?

Comment: @ironcache Yeah sure. It's for a university OOP project. A is actualy an interface for a 2D game tiles, and the subclasses are the specific Tiles, like static tiles, mobs and other stuff.

Comment: @ironcache I wanted a method that would give me all instances of a specific type, let's say i want all monsters, or all walls, etc.. Basically to avoid having a method for each of the tiles.

Comment: @DavidFrickert Understood.  So you have a List that stores all possible tiles, and you want to be able to get all instances of a specific type of tile.  What do you do with the tiles when you get their subclass (say, you get all monsters)?

Comment: @Ironcache I want to set a path for them first (using A* algorithm that i have already implemented) and make them move. Since they can only move after the hero moves, if the Hero as moved, I take the list of monsters, iterate - set path, iterate - move to next tile in path.

Comment: @DavidFrickert It sounds like the monsters are not themselves tiles; they are more so entities that exist on tiles.  Is there any reason you don't store them separately from your tiles?

Comment: @ironcache Well, they need to be drawn on a GUI class that's already designed, so with the logic, everything that gets drawn on the GUI is a Tile, including the Hero and the Monsters themselves. There isn't much design freedom there.

Comment: @DavidFrickert Understood.  Two things: first of all, what you have is likely good for your university project, and my criticisms are only about how I'd treat it in industry; second, it sounds like you have an encapsulation issue.  You essentially want to be able to treat your entities differently in your back-end code (hero, monsters, tiles), but you're storing them all in a general list so that your display code can process them properly.  Your back end shouldn't need to know that your display treats all the elements the same, vica versa w/ back-end treating differently.  Check out MVC.

Comment: @ironcache Thanks for pointing it out! Well i'm trying to get this project good, since, to be honest, I don't think industry-like programming ain't going to be teached in unversity. So what you are saying is that having a List of all tiles is bad practices? I'll check that out and see if it's possible to implement (given the setbacks like not being able to change the GUI class).

Comment: @DavidFrickert Not necessarily.  From the point of view of the display, for example, it should only care about what it's painting.  So, if it's painting tiles on a grid, it knowing about everything in the game as "tiles" isn't inherently bad.  However, in your back-end, these objects are different in nature; your hero is likely controlled by your player, your monsters are moved by an A* algorithm, your walls and floors likely don't move, etc.  In your back-end, you do **not** want everything in the game to be known as generic tiles.  I'll try to post up an answer shortly to clarify this.

Comment: @Ironcache I see, please do if you don't mind. Since this is a bit hard for me to understand right away since I'm still learning java OOP,

Comment: @ironcache Sorry to disturb you, could you post the answer so that i can try to understand better what i should change on my project? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from the comments, it seems to me like there's an encapsulation issue.  Currently, you're storing all of the data as generic `Tile` objects, because your front end just paints tiles.  However, you want the ability to treat these tiles individually in your back-end (IE: being able to get and move all of your monsters), and thus the necessity of the method you've created.

The underlying problem here is that your back-end should never be dependent on how your front end treats data (and vica versa).  Segregating view elements from model elements is a the most common example of encapsulating data in software development.  For example, what you want in your view is a series of paintable tiles:

```
public abstract class Tile {
    public void paintTile() {
        ...
    }
}

...

public class PlayerTile extends Tile {
    @Override
    public void paintTile() {
        super.paintTile();
        paintPlayer();
    }

    public void paintPlayer() {
        ...
    }
}

...

public class View {
    private List<Tile> tiles;

    public void paintGame() {
        ...
        for (Tile tile : tiles) {
            tile.paintTile();
        }
        ...
    } 
}
```

This implementation is fine; the view itself only cares about the game entities as a list of tiles that it can paint.  However, the problem exists when you want to do more with the `Tile` than just paint it (as you're experiencing now).  It doesn't operate intuitively anymore; you need to start digging through this generic list, which clearly wasn't meant to be used in the way we are.

This is where the segregation of your back-end and view comes in; your view doesn't necessarily care about your data in the same way that your back-end does.  So, your model might have something like:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    public void move() {
        ...
    }
}

...

public class PlayerEntity extends Entity {
    @Override
    public void move() {
        // User moves player
    }
}

...

public class MonsterEntity extends Entity {
    @Override
    public void move() {
        // Moved by A* algorithm
    }
}

...

public class Model {
    private PlayerEntity player;
    private List<MonsterEntity> monsters;

    public void gameRound() {
        ...
        player.move();
        ...
        for (MonsterEntity monster : monsters) {
            monster.move();
        }
        ...
    } 
}
```

This pseudo-implementation has irrelevant flaws, but I believe it illustrates the point; on the view side, you have a list of tiles, and that works for the view.  On the back-end side, you have your data stored in a manner that's coherent for the back-end to use.  The implementation, on both ends, is intuitive and fluid.

What is missing here is the glue: what connects the `View` and `Model`?  There's several ways to handle this, but, for the sake of simplicity, lets just say that the view knows about the model, and can request the position of all game entities within the model:

```
public class Model {
    private PlayerEntity player;
    private List<MonsterEntity> monsters;

    public void gameRound() {
        ...
    }

    public List<Entity> getEntities() {
        List<Entity> entities = Lists.newArrayList();
        entities.add(player);
        entities.addAll(monsters);
        ...
        return entities;
    }
}

...

public class View {
    private Model model;
    private List<Tile> tiles;

    public View(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void paintGame() {
        ...
        List<Entity> entities = model.getEntities();
        tiles = convertToTiles(entities);
        ...
        for (Tile tile : tiles) {
            tile.paintTile();
        }
        ...
    }

    private List<Tile> convertToTiles(List<Entity> entities) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will serve to link the two.  However, it's important to note that this implementation has a bit of a design flaw; since the `Model` is directly passing `Entity` object to the `View`, the view is now linked to back-end implementation details, which means that we've increased the coupling between elements that should be distinct.

So what's the workaround?  Well, one option is [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) object that operates between the `Model` and `View`.  This mediator object essentially communicates between the `Model` and `View`, so that they don't need to know anything about the other:

```
public class Model {
    private PlayerEntity player;
    private List<MonsterEntity> monsters;

    public void gameRound() {
        ...
    }

    public List<Entity> getEntities() {
        List<Entity> entities = Lists.newArrayList();
        entities.add(player);
        entities.addAll(monsters);
        ...
        return entities;
    }
}

...

public class View {
    private Presenter presenter;
    private List<Tile> tiles;

    public View(Presenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public void paintGame() {
        ...
        List<Tile> tiles = presenter.getTiles();
        ...
        for (Tile tile : tiles) {
            tile.paintTile();
        }
        ...
    } 
}

...

public class Presenter {
    private Model model;

    public Presenter(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public List<Tile> getTiles() {
        return convertToTiles(model.getEntities());
    } 

    private List<Tile> convertToTiles(List<Entity> entities) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now we have a `View` that doesn't know anything about the `Model` (and vica versa); the `Presenter` object handles communication between them.  You could argue that we've just moved the problem; the `Presenter` object now has to know about both the model objects and the view objects, instead of the `View`.  This is valid to a degree (I will go into that below).  However, acting as a mediator between the `Model` and `View` is the responsibility of the `Presenter`; by [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), this **is** its reason to change.  If the model or view changes how it communicates, then that is the one and only reason for why the `Presenter` should change.  If we look at the implementation without the `Presenter`, then the `View` would have multiple reasons to change (model changes how it communicates, want to add new view functionality), and would be in violation of SRP.

However, looping back the `Presenter` knowing about both the model and view objects, by [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), the Presenter should not be depending directly on the implementation of `Entity` or `Tile`; it should be communicating between the model and view using interfaces.  So the workaround is simple: have Entity and Tile be and `interface` instead of an `abstract class` (and create abstract classes that are used internally, but not communicated to other modules).  Then, the Presenter is communicating between the model and view modules using contractual interfaces, rather than the `Presenter` needing to know anything about the implementation details of either module.

This answer is fairly long-winded, but hopefully it conveys the points I'm trying to get across.  I also recommend taking a look at [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter).

Comment: I see, well I think I could be hard to implement this since my GUI (View class?) is not supposed to be modificated, it extends Observable and is supposed to be observed by something. But i think i understand the back-end changes that need to be done, so I in my Room class, that defines the current Room, will have sort of instance variables representing the Hero, Monsters, and Static Tiles? Sort of like your Model.